# Dygraphs 2.x legend posittioned off the right of graph

Tags: reactjs, legend, dygraphs

I have been trying to update our code to `dygraphs 2.x` from 1.1.1, but I have encountered a issue with the legend.

I believe it is related to the way our page is structured. We are also using `React` so this may also have an impact.

The `dygraph` is on a tab which is initially hidden until the user clicks a button after selecting various options and data sources to generate a time series line chart.

The legend option set to 'always' seems to push the legend off the right of the graph which is not readable by users.Unless they full screen the browser.

After debugging the source I can see that offsetWidth is being used to position the legend and is returning 0.  I can only surmise that because the div the chart is inside is only made visible probably after the chart is drawn is messing the position of the legend.

If I regen the chart while visible the legend appears over top the chart as desired. But if I then hide the chart (by clicking on the other tab) and then show the chart (clicking on it's tab) the legend if off to the right again.

I'm not sure how to workaround this.

Presently I reverted back to 1.1.1 which does not have this issue.

Hope someone can suggest something.

Comment: I’ve had similar issues trying to migrate to v2 and reverted to v1 after investing too much time in upgrading.  Hope someone chimes in to help.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347793/388951

Comment: @danvk also happens after resize(...)